# Открыть полупрозрачное окно поверх существующей активности

Tags: java, android, activity

Изучаю Android. Смотрю на различные популярные приложения и пытаюсь воспроизвести их механику. Наткнулся на Evernote: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote&hl=ru

При нажатии на кнопку "+" (внизу справа) разворачивается на весь экран полупрозрачное меню поверх активности: https://lh6.ggpht.com/AiZ7XjhCSnGhog3Dmwi7wVOrCXSBMD86kMJCl11p88Cu3nQUY-OgaSPqr-BnX4cu9g=h900-rw

Сначала я решил что вызывается фрагмент, но во всех примерах фрагмент встраивался непосредственно в верстку активности и других возможностей я не нашёл. Куда копать? Что читать?

Comment: читать книги по разработке под андроид, как [Б.Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 2017 3-е издание](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/141049718/)

Comment: я почти дочитал книгу: Head First. Программирование для Android 2016. Пока читал не нашёл ответов на свои вопросы. Не уверен что в вашей я найду ответы, учитывая что она тоже направленна на новичков

Comment: Возможно это диалог во весь экран с полупрозрачным фоном

Comment: А разве можно в диалоговое окно добавлять другие элементы управления (кнопки, TextView)? Насколько я понял в диалоговом окне представлены две кнопки (положительная и отрицательная), другие элементы не предусмотрены. Возможно вы не поняли чего именно я хочу добиться, тогда можете посмотреть на вторую ссылку, там показано меню, открытое поверх начальной активности (ссылка c google play. Если боитесь за сохранность ссылки, то перейдите по первой и интересующий меня скриншот будет вторым).